# Regular expression for matching non-whitespace in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, whitespace

I want to use *re.search* to extract the first set of non-whitespace characters. I have the following pseudoscript that recreates my problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
import re

line = "STARC-1.1.1.5             ConsCase    WARNING    Warning"
m = re.search('^[^\S]*?',line)
if m:
    print m.group(0)
```

It seems to be printing the whitespace instead of *STARC-1.1.1.5*

So far as I understand it, this regular expression is saying: 
*At the start of the line, find a set of nonwhitespace characters, don't be greedy*

I was pretty sure this would work, the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) says I can use /S to match whitespace in [], so i'm not sure where the issue is.

Now, I know, I know this probably looks weird, why aren't I using some other function to do this? Well, there's more than one way to skin a cat and i'm still getting the hang of regular expressions in Python so I'd like to know how I can use re.search to extract this field in this fashion.

Comment: here is another one
re.split("\s*", line)[0]

Comment: @melpomene re is greedy. it wont split on an empty string here

Comment: @e4c5 I tried that and got `FutureWarning: split() requires a non-empty pattern match.` With `\s+` I didn't get a warning.

Comment: @melpomene i also tried it in python 2.7 with ipython and got the desired result

Comment: My test was with 3.5.2. I also got the desired result in both cases, but only `\s+` didn't trigger a warning in `re.py:203`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `[^\S]` is a [*negated character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) that is equal to `\s` (whitespace pattern). The `*?` is a lazy quantifier that matches *zero or more characters, but as few as possible*, and when used at the end  of the pattern never actually matches any characters.

Replace you `m = re.search('^[^\S]*?',line)` line with

```
m = re.match(r'\S+',line)
```

or - if you want to also allow an empty string match:

```
m = re.match(r'\S*',line)
```

The `re.match` method anchors the pattern at the start of the string. With `re.search`, you need to keep the `^` anchor at the start of the pattern:

```
m = re.search(r'^\S+',line)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ZjEGRR):

```
import re
line = "STARC-1.1.1.5             ConsCase    WARNING    Warning"
m = re.search('^\S+',line)
if m:
    print m.group(0)
# => STARC-1.1.1.5
```

However, here, in this case, you may just use a mere `split()`:

```
res = line.split() 
print(res[0])
```

See [another Python demo](https://ideone.com/us7zyy).

Answer (score 8):

`\s` matches a whitespace character.

`\S` matches a non-whitespace character.

`[...]` matches a character in the set `...`.

`[^...]` matches a character not in the set `...`.

`[^\S]` matches a character that is not a non-whitespace character, i.e. it matches a whitespace character.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your re.search as below, \S finds non-whitespace character, and + searches for one or more times. Python starts to search from first character.

```
import re
line = "STARC-1.1.1.5             ConsCase    WARNING    Warning"
m = re.search('\S+',line)
print(m.group(0))
```

Comment: Code whithout explanation is useless. And what question are you answering?

Comment: (Re)read the question: `I want to use re.search to extract the first set of non-whitespace characters.`

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
line = "STARC-1.1.1.5             ConsCase    WARNING    Warning"
m = re.search('S.+[0-9]',line)
print(m.group(0))
```

The re.search returns the match, so use the alphabets and numbers and print the match as mentioned in the code. If you print only the variable it prints it as match 1.
Hope this answers your question

```
m = re.search('[A-Z].+[0-9]',line)
```

Changing the re.search to the capital letters will find from CAPS A to Z,
vice vers if you change it to small letters as

```
m = re.search('[a-z].+[0-9]',line)
```

it will find only small letters, sometimes you should highlight the symbols too, to search from it or to search upto the characters before that symbol.

Comment: It looks like the author of the question wanted to extract the first set of *any* non-whitespace characters. This solution assumes that all the extracted string begin with alphabet characters and end with numeric characters. Though the author's example match this pattern the question is about any non-whitespace characters.

Comment: Instead of posting a second, extended answer it'd be better to simply edit your first answer to include the additional information. Also note that the original comment from _@Toto: (Re)read the question: `I want to use re.search to extract the first set of non-whitespace characters.`_ still applies. Your suggested regular expression matches OP's example `STARC-1.1.1.5` but is doesn't match  `first set of non-whitespace characters.`